# gnome-screenshot produces blank png files in mint 17

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, gnome, screenshot

This produces a blank png file in mint 17, but works fine in ubuntu 12:

> gnome-screenshot

Opening the resulting Screenshot file in the ~/Pictures directory shows completely blank image (all black).  Opening the png file with another viewer shows the same thing.

Trying the command with the -a options and then dragging a specific area also produces a blank png file in the Pictures directory

> gnome-screenshot -a

I'm running Mint 17 in a virtual machine in virtualbox.  Yes, Guest Additions has been run and the rest of the virtual machine operations are fine.

Comment: I also get blank png files from the 'shutter' screenshot program.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching Google?

Try these:

http://www.electrobucket.com/linux/screenshot-print-screen-is-not-working-in-linux-mint-14

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=56003

From what I've read on those pages, its a problem thats been around a while but there are a few ideas on how to fix it. There are more pages but I can only post 2 links max.

Mark L.

Comment: External links can break, in which case your answer would have little value.  Please include the essential information in your answer and use the links for attribution and further information.  With a little more rep, you could leave this post as a helpful suggestion in the form of a comment.

Comment: Thanks Mark, and yes, I have been all over google searches.  The first link you provided offers common suggestions like creating a shortcut for those who need that, but doesn't address my problem.  The second link has several people acknowledging the same problem with a solution to switch to Mint's Mate version from Cinnamon.  I don't want to have to step back and can't believe there isn't a solution for this.  So, I'm still quite Stuck.  :-(

Comment: One positive comment I got from the second link that was new to me is invoke the 'host + e' key sequence and save the png image to the host.  It's a bit tedious to then have to fetch the file from the host, and it's a fullscreen image which then has to be cropped, but at least it's something.